# Recursive function python, cannot print an output

Tags: python, printing, recursion

I have just started to program in python, and I am stuck with a problem regarding recursion.

The program seems to compile, however, the print output is not shown.

Here is the program:

```
print 'type s word'
s = raw_input()
print 'enter a number'
n = raw_input()

def print_n(s, n):

 if n<=0:
  return 
 print s
 print_n(s, n-1)
```

the output i get is:

```
xxxx@xxxx-Satellite-L600:~/Desktop$ python 5exp3.py
type s string
hello
add the number of recursions
4
xxxx@xxxx-Satellite-L600:~/Desktop$
```

What is wrong, and how can I get the program to show an output?

Comment: I recommend using more than one space for your indentation level.

Comment: The code you show doesn't actually call the recursive function... if it did you would get an exception as `raw_input` returns strings which you must convert to integers with `int`.

Comment: You should also use `return print_n(s, n-1)`, when calling the function recursively, though it might not cause any problem in this case, but keep that in mind for future uses.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary:  That seems unnecessary here.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes I mentioned that, I just wanted to tell the OP that it can be useful when he's returning values from function, instead of just printing, coz in that case the function will return `None`.

Answer (score 5):

Your posted code defines the function `print_n` but never calls it.  After the function definition place a `print_n(s, n)`.

Once you do this you'll find some errors caused by the fact the `n` is currently a string (`raw_input` returns a string).  Use `int(a_string)` to convert a string to an integer.  Calling your function like this will solve the issue

```
print_n(s, int(n))
```

Or do

```
n = int(raw_input())
```

The complete code:

```
s = raw_input('type a word: ')
n = int(raw_input('enter a number: '))

def print_n(s, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 
    print s
    print_n(s, n-1)

print_n(s, n)
```

Answer (score 2):

try `n = raw_input()` -> `n = int(raw_input())`

Comment: You are correct that `n` needs to be an integer, but the initial issue is that he never calls the `print_n`.  Otherwise, he would have received `TypeError` on the first recursion.  (It would not have exited early because `"string" <= 0"` evaluates to `False` in Python 2).